# How to pass an array of arrays to Java function?

Tags: nativescript

I want to create in *JavaScript* a

```
new android.content.res.ColorStateList(states,colors)
```

which is defined as

```
public ColorStateList (int[][] states, int[] colors)
```

I cannot figure out how to pass the `int[][] states` parameter.

---

**I've tried**:

A.

```
var states = [
    [android.R.attr.state_pressed],
    [android.R.attr.state_enabled],
];
```

result:

```
Error: Cannot marshal JavaScript argument 16842919,16842910 at index 0 to Java type.
```

*(16842919,16842910 are the two constants in the array.)*

B.

```
var states = Array(2);
states[0] = Array.create("int",1);
states[0][0] = android.R.attr.state_pressed;
states[1] = Array.create("int",1);
states[1][0] = android.R.attr.state_enabled;
```

result:

```
Cannot marshal JavaScript argument [I@8033d59,[I@1e86d1e at index 0 to Java type.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
var states = Array.create("[I",2);
states[0] = Array.create("int",1);
states[0][0] = android.R.attr.state_pressed;
states[1] = Array.create("int",1);
states[1][0] = android.R.attr.state_enabled;
```

More info here: [Java to JavaScript Conversion: Array](https://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/android/marshalling/java-to-js#array)

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to use `Array.create()`? In the [documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/android/marshalling/java-to-js#array), it says "Occasionally you have to create Java arrays from JavaScript. For this scenario we added method create to built-in JavaScript Array object."

This sentence describes what you are trying to do IMO.

Comment: Yes, after another hour of searching I found it, too. Thank you.